# Sylius and Behat

Tags: behat, sylius

I need to add my own behat tests to a sylius based application. I plan to do this from my own bundle.

Reading doc at http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/behat/how-to-add-new-context.html is not clear to me how could i add context from my own bundle.

Is this possible? Doc says you need to do this in one of the files at          src/Sylius/Behat/Resources/config/services/contexts/

So, do i need to add them there or can i add new ones from my own bundle? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, by configuring a `MultiContainerExtension` in your behat.yml file.

```
    Sylius\Behat\Extension\MultiContainerExtension:
        imports:
            - "src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.xml"
```

With this config you can place all of your services in this file or import them. Just like regular symfony services. It is defined similar way [here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Behat/Resources/config/profiles/default.yml#L49).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have moved to `FriendsOfBehat\ContextServiceExtension` in the first beta (1.0.0-beta.1) release.

I guess it's working the same way:

```
FriendsOfBehat\ContextServiceExtension:
        imports:
            - "/www/vvc/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Behat/Resources/config/services.xml"
            - "/www/vvc/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/behat_services.xml"
```

And don't forget to rename your `contexts_as_services` to `contexts_services` if your are upgrading